# How to use pivot points for a sell/buy order?

Tags: data, trading

I have implemented some trading strategies like macd and sma. When the lines are crossing they give a sell or buy signal.

Now I have calculated pivot points of one day

```
    last_day['Pivot'] = (max_value + min_value + close)/3
    last_day['R1'] = 2*last_day['Pivot'] - min_value
    last_day['S1'] = 2*last_day['Pivot'] - max_value
    last_day['R2'] = last_day['Pivot'] + (max_value - min_value)
    last_day['S2'] = last_day['Pivot'] - (max_value - min_value)
    last_day['R3'] = last_day['Pivot'] + 2*(max_value - min_value)
    last_day['S3'] = last_day['Pivot'] - 2*(max_value - min_value)
    return last_day
```

my data now looks like this:

```
                    timestamp      open      high       low     close    volume      macd         macds         macdh  open_5_sma  open_10_sma macd_advice msa_advice     Pivot
1  2020-10-13T19:30:00.000Z  0.033259  0.033273  0.033223  0.033244  1262.011 -0.000035 -3.931010e-05  4.144859e-06    0.033236     0.033225        HOLD        BUY  0.033388         
2  2020-10-13T19:45:00.000Z  0.033244  0.033248  0.033211  0.033211  1068.909 -0.000036 -3.858108e-05  2.916057e-06    0.033239     0.033224        HOLD       HOLD  0.033388         
3  2020-10-13T20:00:00.000Z  0.033211  0.033216  0.033181  0.033211  1329.222 -0.000036 -3.799490e-05  2.344739e-06    0.033235     0.033219        HOLD       HOLD  0.033388         
4  2020-10-13T20:15:00.000Z  0.033211  0.033231  0.033192  0.033194  1109.637 -0.000037 -3.771359e-05  1.125225e-06    0.033238     0.033221        HOLD       HOLD  0.033388         
5  2020-10-13T20:30:00.000Z  0.033193  0.033199  0.033161  0.033165   597.887 -0.000039 -3.801485e-05 -1.205013e-06    0.033224     0.033226        SELL       SELL  0.033388
```

In the data above I've only added Pivots now, I'm able to add S1, S2, S3 and R1, R2, R3

How can I create a buy/sell strategy using this data? I don't need code of course but just someone who can explain when you know when you have to buy or sell something depending on the position of the current price depending on the pivot point (or R1/S1).

Comment: I do not do this, but if you want to trade pivots in a trend-following manner, you would buy when it "breaks out" (goes sligthy above one of the Rn points), short when it goes slightly below one of the Sn points. "slightly" could mean one tick or a few ticks. (But don't do this without further investigation on your part. I have no idea if it works or not).